# Installing different Eclipse IDE distro vs. installing plugins to existing Eclipse IDE

Tags: php, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-neon

Currently, I'm using [Eclipse Neon](http://www.eclipse.org/neon/) and I'm thinking about coding in PHP. Usually, I just add the appropriate plugins; but this one got me thinking on whether I should install [Eclipse for PHP Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/neon1a) instead.

Any thoughts on the difference between installing [PHP plugins](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest/) vs. installing Eclipse distro for PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to have an Eclipse installation that is tailored to the actual needs. Therefore, if your workspace holds only PHP projects, I'd recommend using the *Eclipse for PHP Developers* package in your case,

Ideally, it wouldn't matter having many (unrelated) plug-ins within a single installation. But in reality, installing many plug-ins may

- increase the time needed at startup, because the extensions of all plug-ins need to be read
- increase the likelihood of plug-ins not working well together
- increase UI clutter caused by contributions of the many plug-ins